# PHP table of current month with date on each row

Tags: php, date, calendar, html-table, timestamp

(See screenshot:) I want to make a table, where people can choose, on which days of the month they can work. They can choose between 3 shifts each day (also more than one each day possible).

1. col: day & date of the current month (don't show Mondays & Tuesdays)
   2.–4.col: checkboxes for each shift (each checkbox needs a different name, e.g. "131201Schicht1"

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Show us some example code of what You've done, should it show the entire month ?

Comment: I'm very new to php and tried customize this calendar table, but got lost: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/build-a-calendar-table/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before doing any php work, you need to create the html form first, then it'll be clear what needs to be generated by php and what wouldn't be. here's the HTML I came up with

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>Current month name</td>
        <td>Schicht 1</td>
        <td>Schicht 2</td>
        <td>Schicht 3</td>        
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <input type="check">
        <td>Sun. 1</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="131201Schicht1" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="131201Schicht2" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="131201Schicht3" value=""></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then using the following PHP code, we get the main pieces of info we need to populate the table with:

```
<?php
    //I added this to make it easy to add more shifts
    $number_of_shifts = 3;
    $now    =   time();
    $day    =   1; //Just a day counter
    $month  =   date('m', $now);
    $year   =   date('Y', $now);

    // number of days in this current month
    $days_in_month = cal_days_in_month(0, $month, $year);
?>
```

Then we just need to run the following code to generate our own table with rules like leaving out specific days, etc..

```
<?php
    $number_of_shifts = 3;
    $now    =   time();
    $day    =   1;
    $month  =   date('m', $now);
    $year   =   date('Y', $now);
    $days_in_month = cal_days_in_month(0, $month, $year);
?>
<html>
<body>
<table border="1" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td><? echo date('F', $now).' '.$year; ?></td>
        <? for ($i=1; $i < $number_of_shifts+1; $i++)
        {
            echo "<td>Schicht $i</td>";
        }
        ?>
    </tr>
    <?php while ($day <= $days_in_month)
    {
        $timeForDay = mktime(0,0,0,$month, $day, $year);
        $dayName = date('D', $timeForDay);
        if($dayName != 'Mon' && $dayName != 'Tue')
        {
    ?>
        <tr>
        <?php
            echo '<td> '.$dayName.' '.$day.' </td>';
            $shiftId = date('ydm', $timeForDay);
            for ($i=1; $i < $number_of_shifts+1; $i++)
            {
                echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="'.$shiftId.'Schicht'.$i.'" value=""></td>';
            }
        ?>
        </tr>
    <?
        }
    $day++;
    }
    ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

This is just a quick messy piece of code, you shouldn't use that in production, I'm just showing you a technique on how it can be done and isn't tested !

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts Mostafa. This is a wonderful solution. It helps me very much understand. I will try to customize it and learn from this.

Comment: i'm glad it helped, let us know if you need more assistance !